# Coding Visual Elements In C# Using Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Pre-Note: I have never done anything when it comes to coding visual elements. By this I don't mean UI-Elements ETC, but rather like the examples shown below. I am not asking for a slab of code, I want to do it on my own but I have no clue where to even start looking, nor do I know the name of what I am trying to do. Thank you~

Example Image 1*: https://www.gry-online.pl/galeria/galeria_duze3/618164413.jpg

 As can be seen in Diablo when the character reaches a location where an obstacle blocks the player vision they are hidden and/or made transparent. This is NOT what I am hoping to make as this seems like an easy thing to do.

Example Image 2*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RR8o.jpg

I am wanting to make something like this. When the character goes behind an obstacle the parts of the character have their outline shown through the object.

TLDR: I have no clue what I'm doing when it comes to what I hope to accomplish. Example 2 is the product I wish to reproduce (Where you can see the Characters outline behind objects that would otherwise block the player from seeing their character's location.) Example 1 is what I do NOT want.
I don't want to be given code or a finished project, I just want pointed in the right direction so I can try and get this working on my own first :D I just have no clue where to look or what this is called. Thank you ~

Please Note: I am not being lazy and not looking it up online. I have no clue what I would even look up is the issue. I am totally lost atm ;-;

Comment: This question is really way too broad, and borders on asking for a tutorial, but I'll throw you a bone;  try researching transparent occlusion.

Comment: Ok, Let me ask a different question. Is there a way for me to create a shader that creates an outline that is always visible even when hidden behind other game objects? And if there is not is there any way to create a like effect?

Comment: Q: "Is there a way to...." A: "Yes."  That doesn't really help your cause.  Again, I suggest researching Occlusion, Transparencies, and how they interact.

Comment: If you know about shaders, you already know the answer. Also, never explain what you don't want to do because it may be confusing. As Claies did, I am going to give you a small hint: https://gitee.com/liyonghelpme/unityRpg/blob/master/Assets/shaders/playerShader.shader

Comment: My project made "wall object" to go transparent when something or someone is behind to show that object. Not a solution of what you asked but might be a alternative.